# Forcing the color of density plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I've got two overlapping density functions I created as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(2)
a =rnorm(100)
b = rnorm(100,.5,1.2)
c = rnorm(100,.3,1.2)
data <- rbind( data.frame(type="a", lr=a), data.frame(type="b", lr=b))
data2 <- rbind( data.frame(type="b", lr=b), data.frame(type="c", lr=c))
m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=lr))
m <- m + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4) 
m2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=lr))
m2 <- m2 + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4)
```

which produces these two nice plots:

```
m
```

[image]

```
m2
```

[image]

My problem is that ggplot alphabetically decides the red and blue colours and as you see in first one "b" is blue but in the second one "b" is red.
I don't know how to force the "b" to be red.
How can I select the colours for each of them?

Comment: Thanks a lot Henrik, I don't know how to vote you for your edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## One color for all groups

It sounds like you want *both* density plots to be red.  In that case, you can use `group` instead of `fill` within `aes` to indicate the grouping variable, and then set the `fill` color for the whole graph, as follows:

`m <- m + geom_density(aes(`**`group=factor(type)), fill="#ff0000"`**`, size=2, alpha=.4)`

## Specific colors for each group

But if you're actually trying to set specific colors for each group, then you can use `scale_fill_manual`. There are two ways to do this: either with a *named* vector of colors, or with two vectors--one with colors, and one with group names.  Here it is from the [docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html):

> **`values`** a set of aesthetic values to map data values to. If this is a named vector, then the values will be matched based on the names. If
>   unnamed, values will be matched in order (usually alphabetical) with
>   the limits of the scale. Any data values that don't match will be
>   given `na.value`.

### 1. Using a Named Vector

```
groupColors <- c(a="#00ff00", b="#ff0000", c="#0000ff")

m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=lr))
m <- m + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=groupColors)
m2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=lr))
m2 <- m2 + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=groupColors)
```

### 2. Using Two Vectors

```
groupLimits <- c("a", "b", "c")
groupColors <- c("#00ff00", "#ff0000", "#0000ff")

m <- ggplot(data, aes(x=lr))
m <- m + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=groupColors, limits=groupLimits)
m2 <- ggplot(data2, aes(x=lr))
m2 <- m2 + geom_density(aes(fill=factor(type)), size=2, alpha=.4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=groupColors, limits=groupLimits)
```

One key difference in this approach is that `groupLimits` will control the order in which the different groups appear in the legend (and, in this case, will also force all three groups to appear).

Comment: I was looking for specific colour and your second method is the perfect answer.Unfortunately I have to have 15 points to be able to vote.

Comment: You should be able to vote now @shahram, don't forget to accept the answer as well.